# Change css with OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to switch the `display:block` part of `#about{` with `display:none` part of `#downloads` with a `OnClick`?

```
#about {
    position:relative;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:800px;
    height:450px;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
    border:solid 2px #000000;
    background-color:#448efc;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    display:block
}
#downloads {
    position:relative;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:800px;
    height:450px;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
    border:solid 2px #000000;
    background-color:#448efc;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    display:none
}
```

heres my OnClick Code`<a href="#downloads" onclick="somthing?">` im not sure if its possible do any of you know how?

Comment: Why do you want to change the css rule, instead change the class or just use jquery .show(), .hide()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the css using jquery.

```
<a href="#downloads" onclick="$('#about').css("display", "none");">
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest something like this:

```css
#about, #downloads {
    /* all of the CSS rules EXCEPT display here */
}
.hidden {display:none}
```

Then your HTML should be:

```
<div id="about">...</div>
<div id="downlaods" class="hidden">...</div>
```

Now your link can be:

```
<a href="#downloads" onClick="document.getElementById('about').className = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('downloads').className = '';">Downloads</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are actually looking for jQuery [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). because it makes no sense keeping onclick event on the element which has already `display: none`.

```
<div id="about" onclick="$('#downloads').toggle()"></div>
<div id="downloads" onclick="$('#about').toggle()"></div>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dEsCV/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to **hide** `#about`:

```
$('#downloads').click(function() {
    $('#about').hide();
});
```

With this, there's no need to add `onclick` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my quotesmarks, code below fully works for me....

```
<form action="uploadprofileaccept.php" 
class="dropzone" onclick="$('#imageform').css('display', 'none');">
</form>
```